# Random walks on resistive network

Tags: electrical-resistance, probability, electrical-engineering

I have been referring to a paper
http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0405135 to determine the effective resistance using random walks for an infinite square resistive lattice

Though the author seems to indicate this as a simple problem
(maybe i am missing something) i have been unable to prove this

$∆_{AB}$ = $\frac{1}{2p_{AB}}$

where,

$∆_{AB}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$
$(P_{n}(A) − P{n}(B))$

$P_{n}(x):$Probability that a Random walker after n steps is found at x

$p_{AB}:$Probability that a
random walker, starting at A, gets to B before returning to A

Could someone please help me with this ?

(For more detailed description refer to the link)

Answer (score 2):

One finds a full explanation of this formula and much more about the connection between random walks and electric networks in the little gem *Random walks and electric networks* by Peter G. Doyle and J. Laurie Snell, [freely available](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001057).

Comment: I think that link-only answers are frowned on here. Could you condense the explanation for us?